Document reference in Microsoft Teams bot with Teams SDK
I'm struggling to discover how can I change the way the document references are presented by my teams bot in microsoft teams.
Current document reference
This is the way the reference is shown but I want those numbers to send the user directly to the document used to generate this response.
If it is possible, I would like to do it without changing the design of the reference but it is ok if not possible.
In the perfect scenario, I want the reference to have both the descprition of the file (as it already has) and a hyperlink to the actual document but, if I have to choose one I'll end up staying with the link only. Thanks!

The functionality you want to implement doesn't seem to be feasible. To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in Teams Feedback Portal.
